# JNI: How to pass "unsigned char* " from C++ to java

Tags: java, c++, c, visual-studio-2005, java-native-interface

I have a 'unsigned char *' and I want to pass it on to the Java code using JNI
I have tried it in the following way

```
jstring test1;  
std::string str(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ucptest));  
test1 = env->NewStringUTF(str.c_str());
```

where 'ucptest' is 'unsigned char *' and has ascii values in it.
this code works and I can successfully pass jstring to Java code, but in the load call I am seeing crash in JVM.

What could be the possible reason for the crash? crash is inconsistence, which could mean memory corruption.

Can someone suggest a better way to pass 'unsigned char*' to Java?

any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to pass a string, not a pointer, so say so. Passing a pointer into Java would be as easy as casting it to an integer, but that would be useless because Java code couldn't do anything with the pointer.

Comment: No, I have legacy code with 'unsigned char*' which I have to pass to java

Comment: @user578742 is ucptest Null terminated?

Comment: @josefx ucptest is not null terminated, but I have a length variable as part of the same structure as ucptest and i will be reading only len char's from ucptest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, and thought I would share the same, so that others could use it.

Initially I was converting `char*` to C++ String and then passing it to Java `String`.  This was working just fine, until we had "0" in the string I was trying to convert.  This was causing a crash.

Finally, I used a byte array to pass on the value to server.  This is working perfectly.

```
jbyteArray jbArray = env->NewByteArray((int)call.len);
env->SetByteArrayRegion(jbArray, 0, (int)call.len, (jbyte*)call.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why your adding in the extra casting step, java strings are unicode, `unsigned char *` or `wchar_t *` or `std::wstring().c_str()` can be used more directly.

```
unsigned char * ucptest=L"somestring";
jstring test1;  
std::string str(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ucptest));  
test1 = env->NewStringUTF(str.c_str());

jstring test2 = env->NewString(ucptest,wcslen(ucptest));
```

Comment: I tried "env->NewString" however I am seeing the following compile time errors error.                                

         C2664: 'JNIEnv_::NewString' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned char *' to 'const jchar *' Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Answer (score 0):

The [`std::string` constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) you are using expects a null terminated c-string. The constructor will read until it finds a nul character, this can cause the crash. You should use a different constructor if your string is not nul terminated (`std::string(char*,size_t)`).

Comment: after calling the std::string ctor, i am assigning null at the end of the string

str[len] = null;

where len is the variable which has count of total values in 'unsigned char*'

Comment: @user578742 how does that help the string ctor? Without the nul the ctor does not know where to stop reading.

Comment: ok, I would try out <code> std::string(char*,size_t) </code>

Is there any other way to pass the values of 'unsigned char *' to java 
code? without doing casting

Answer (score 0):

In your case, line `env->NewStringUTF(str.c_str());` must be inside conditional block for checking `getStaticMethodInfo`:

code can be framed as:

```
JniMethodInfo t;

if (JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(t,<ANDROID CLASS PATH>,<METHOD NAME>,<PARAM TYPE>)) {

    jstring jstr    =   t.env->NewStringUTF(<CONST CHAR* TYPE DATA>);
    ...........CALL TO JAVA METHOD THROUGH JNI
    t.env->DeleteLocalRef(t.classID);

}
```