# How to obtain jchar* from std::string?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am writing a JNI application.  In my C++ code, I have  `std::string`.  I need to obtain a `jchar *` from it to pass to a Java function.  How do I do this?

Comment: Maybe related to [JNI: How to pass “unsigned char* ” from C++ to java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716223/jni-how-to-pass-unsigned-char-from-c-to-java)?

Comment: Yes, that's it.  The answer below contains the relevant line of code (also in the link you provided).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `env->NewStringUTF()`, to create a new java-string from a `char*`.

Comment: Make sure you understand all of the string encoding issues, too.